# (When/How often/Where) should I show my admob insterstitial ads?

Tags: android, applications, advertisement, efficiency

I am developing an Android app about jokes, this is a simple schema about it:

[image: simple schema]

I want to implement admob interstitial ads and I would like to know about the best way to do it. For example:

- Where are the best places to show my full screen ads? I have read the best option is to put them between screen transitions (jokes loading) and I have decided to follow this advice but I find more doubts.
- How often should I display an ad to the user in order to avoid disturb him and don't reduce so much my earnings?
- What is the best way to manage a count of ad views by the user in my Java code, to decide if it is a good moment to load another ad and show it?

If you consider I am missing something or you have any other advice for me, it will be welcome.

Comment: Splash screens aren't common anymore. Best to get rid of that and get your content in front of your users as soon as possible. For the same reason, you might not want to put full-screen ads in the flow at all. (If I click to see a joke and I see an ad instead, I'll close the browser window.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding interstitial ads at any point in the hierachy you describe sounds probably isn't ideal. You don't want to interrupt the user journey while they are getting to the content.

I assume there would be a way for a user to cycle through jokes (prev/next type functionality) and this would be the best place for those ads. Every X jokes show an ad.

In terms of how often to show an advert the best thing to do here is gather some data. Recording exit rates for example might be a good indicator of how annoying the ads are to the user. There is no magic number, only what works for your particular app.

Make a hypothesis, gather data, review. You will be able to discover what works for you.

The Java question is probably better asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, I expected something like this. I will follow your advice, putting interstitial ads every x jokes. I have thought that a good "x" would be 7. What do you think? Is it too fast or good?

Comment: Many successful apps didn't even think about monetising until they had built a large and loyal user base. I would err on the side of caution and have very few, if any, ads to begin with. Measure the impact the ads have on your reviews and usage stats, you will then have some information to help you find the right balance between earning money and keeping users happy.